# How to return a variable from inside a for loop

Tags: java, variables, loops, return, break

I am trying to return the index of the element containing character 'r' which has charcater 'u' as its successor. The following piece of code always returns the varialbe ruindex =0.
Please suggest edits in the code.

```
    int ruindex=0;
    if (s1[0]=='h') {
        s2[0] = 'h';
        s2[1] = 't';
        s2[2] = 't';
        s2[3] = 'p';
        s2[4] = ':';
        s2[5] = '/';
        s2[6] = '/';

        for (int i=4; i < s1.length-1; i++) {
            if (s1[i]=='r' && s1[i+1]=='u') {
                ruindex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

It is just a part of my overall code. Yes there is a reason why I want to start from i=4. What I wish to do is that whenever I encounter 'r' and 'u' together in the character array, I want to return the index of that 'r'.

Comment: First of all: format your code in a readable way

Comment: I doubt that this code will compile.

Comment: Is there a reason you're starting from `i=4`, you're only setting up `s2` if the first value of `s1` is `h`, there isn't this `r` in `s2` you're looking for and what does `s1` and `s2` mean here, why are there 2 separate variables? Please elaborate on your requirements and provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Add declaration of `s1`

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
String s2 = new String(s1);
s2.indexOf("ru");
```

?

Comment: Given a string "hlolrulolru", would the above piece of code return 4?

Comment: do you have google "installed" to search for the java doc of  indexOf method of String class? :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code does affect index of first encountered "ru" to ruindex variable if arrays are initialized and populated. However you should change the loop to

```
for (int i = 4; i < s1.length - 1; i++) {
```

or you'll get an ArrayOutOfBoundsException if 'r' is the last character of the array and there are no matches before.

Anyway it seems to me that you should consider working with Strings, rather than arrays. You'll be able to use dedicated methods to achieve your goal or even use regular expressions if your goal becomes more complicate than this.